# Failed to connect AWS RDS postgresql database from tomcat running on elastic beanstalk

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-rds

I deployed a java servlet application to a tomcat 8.5 environemnt in elastic beanstalk, running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2/4.3.11.

I also created a PostgreSQL database in AWS RDS, but when my app is trying to connect the database, I get the following error:
`The authentication type 10 is not supported. Check that you have configured the pg_hba.conf file to include the client's IP address or subnet, and that it is using an authentication scheme supported by the driver.`

I tried to make a normal JDBC connection to the database, I copied the database details connection parameters (host, db name, username, password, port) to environment properties and used this code in the java webapp:

```
if (System.getProperty("RDS_HOSTNAME") != null) {
                try {
                    Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
                    String dbName = System.getProperty("RDS_DB_NAME");
                    String userName = System.getProperty("RDS_USERNAME");
                    String password = System.getProperty("RDS_PASSWORD");
                    String hostname = System.getProperty("RDS_HOSTNAME");
                    String port = System.getProperty("RDS_PORT");
                    String jdbcUrl = "jdbc:postgresql://" + hostname + ":" + port + "/" + dbName + "?sslmode=require&user=" + userName
                            + "&password=" + password;
                    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcUrl);
                    return con;
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                    throw e;
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    throw e;
                }
            }
```

Can someone please help a noob in SQL databases how to solve this problem? Thank in advance

Comment: Can you try a more standard approach like [the docs](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/use/) recommend - i.e. using properties?  The user name and password may contain unsupported characters.

Comment: @erik258 The answers in your post helped me to solve the problem, thank for the help